# Python crashes when plotting with matplotlib in module importing swig generated wrapper

Tags: python, crash, matplotlib, swig, show

I have a python module that imports a module generated with swig. When I try to call the show() function of matplotlib later in that module, python crashes without any hint, what went wrong. When I comment the import statement with the swig generated module out, everything works fine.
Does anybody have a clue to what could be the reason for this behaviour? I'm aware that this is a very unspecific formulation of the problem. But, I don't expect a solution to my problem, just a hint to where I could look at to find the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Could it be related to namespace pollution? If you switch the order of the imports (for the swig module and matplotlib) does the error change? It might also help if you post at least the import statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with running the script under gdb and looking at the stack trace.  Recent versions of gdb have built in support for python debugging.

```
$ gdb python
(gdb) run /path/to/script.py
# wait for crash #
(gdb) bt
# stack trace here #
```

More [information here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb).

Comment: You could also try running Python in verbose mode by using python -v.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you call figure.show instead of plt.show()

The following script crash:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot([25, 43, 65], [3500, 5500, 5800])

fig.show() # use plt.show() instead
```

This script is working fine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot([25, 43, 65], [3500, 5500, 5800])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Actually, it does not crash.  It just finishes end exits, since fig.show() will not wait for the plot window to close. Also, I don't see how that could be in any way affected by a precence of another module.